# SetText to Button in horizontal swipe view paging

Tags: android, swing, button, horizontalscrollview

I have simple swiping page example whit three page.
There are one button on each of three page "Yellow Button", "Blue Button", "Red Button".
I want to change the name of buttons like "Yellow Button" to "+", how can i do that?
I try to changed in "onClickYellowButton" method but that's not change until user press a key and i want to change right after showing page.
thanks for any help.

Customviewpager

```
  public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0: {
        resId = R.layout.page_1;
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        resId = R.layout.page_2;
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        resId = R.layout.page_3;
        break;
    }
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create and set adapter
    CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.customviewpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(1);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Click button on blue page
 */
public void onClickBlueButton(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Blue screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/**
 * Click button on yellow page
 */
public void onClickYellowButton(View v) {
 Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYellow);
    b.setText("+");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yellow screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/**
 * Click button on red page
 */
public void onClickRedButton(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Red screen",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/customviewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Page 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/blue"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBlue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_blue"
    android:onClick="@string/listenerBlueButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Page 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/yellow"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonYellow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_yellow"
    android:onClick="@string/listenerYellowButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Page 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/red"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonRed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_red"
    android:onClick="@string/listenerRedButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by setting "setOnPageChangeListener" event. In onPageSelected event, you can write your logic btn.setText("+"); here but you need to find out which button is visible currently via some mandane logic.

```
 myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: that's work but problem is user must be swipe page one time atleast to change be acted.how can i set BlueButton in page0 when activity's up for first time.

Comment: That you can set in your createView function only because you know that first page is the default one to get loaded initially. Therefore add your logic for initial page in CreateView function.

Answer (score 0):

The text displayed in each button at startup is defined your layout.xml e.g. here:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonYellow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_yellow" // This is where you define the text
    android:onClick="@string/listenerYellowButton" />
```

if you want to change the text I suggest you change the corresponding string resource in your strings.xml.